# Different landscape and portrait design

Tags: ios, iphone, landscape, landscape-portrait, portrait

Hi i have a portrait design of my app and i want to change this design when the user rotate the device.

Something like that:

Portrait:

**Button 1  -  Button 2**

**Button 3  -  Button 4**

Landscape:

**Button 1  -  Button 2  -  Button 3 -  Button 4**

I don't know if the next way is the best:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                       name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                       object:nil];
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)    {
        HERE CHANGE THE CONSTRAINS
    }
}
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can do this with using Size Class. i did this... 
1. First Desigh Screen in wAny - hAny and set all Constrains
2. For Portrait select wCompact - hRegular and go to Size inspector
3. In Descendant Constrains there are many Constrains select one by one (double click on that)
4. you can see two + button. perss it and select wCompact - hRegular. it shownew field set Constrains (Size). do this for all Constrains.
5. Now for Landscape in storybord select wRegular - hCompact and do this same...
```

it is  Work like if - else if condition... if (Portrait){ this } else if (Landscape) { this }

Answer (score 0):

Why not use size classes?  A size class is a property applied to any view or view controller that represents the amount of content that can be displayed in a given horizontal or vertical dimension. Size classes are available since iOS8. Already almost 90% of devices use iOS8 but of course it depends on requirements you have.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

If you want to support older iOS versions, your approach is also good.

Comment: Thanks! one more question. In size classes, what are the w and h for landscape?

Comment: It depends from the device. It is different for iPad and iPhone. When you use autolayout you shouldn't pay too much attention to this.  Check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial there is a chapter regarding size classes. It's nice to have a good understanding of autolayout/size classes before you start implementing.